# Simplify: $\frac{3x}{x+2} - \frac{4x}{2-x} - \frac{2x-1}{x^2-4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$\frac{3x}{x+2} - \frac{4x}{2-x} - \frac{2x-1}{x^2-4}$$

1. First I expanded $x²-4$ into $(x+2)(x-2)$. There are 3 denominators.
2. So I multiplied the numerators into: $$\frac{3x(x+2)(2-x)}{(x+2)(x-2)(2-x)} - \frac{4x(x+2)(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)(2-x)} - \frac{2x-1(2-x)}{(x+2)(x-2)(2-x)} $$

I then tried 2 different approaches:

1. Calculated it without eliminating the denominator into: $$\frac{-6x²-5x+2}{(x+2)(x-2)(2-x)}$$
2. Calculated it by multiplying it out to: $$\frac{-6x+2x²+2}{(x+2)(x-2)(2-x)}$$

I can't seem to simplify them further and so they seem incorrect. Something I missed? Help!

Comment: In the equation, the last term is $x^2/4$, then you talk about $x^2-4$. Which is correct?

Comment: x²−4 is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common denominator is not what you have, it is $(x-2)(x+2)$. In your first step, rewrite $$-\frac{4x}{2-x}$$ into $$+\frac{4x}{x-2}$$

Comment: So what you mean is that −4x/2−x means -4x/-x-2?

Comment: NO, I mean that $$-\frac{4x}{2-x} = \frac{4x}{-(2-x)} = \frac{4x}{x-2}.$$

Comment: Oh wow. I learned something new. Thanks I'm gonna redo it. But does that mean that 4x is now a plus?

Comment: What do you mean yo learned something new? You MUST have known that if you are solving the kind of problems you posted.

Comment: But does that mean that the last part is -(x²-4)= -x²+4? Im confussed...

Comment: @user160137 That is of course true. After all, $-(a+b) = -a - b$. But you don't *have* to use that equality. You can write your expression as $\frac{3x}{x+2} + \frac{4x}{x-2} - \frac{2x-1}{x^2-4}$

Comment: Why should I "must have known it"? I wouldn't have posted it if I knew that. After reading how to solve these I am solving problems in order to progress. What else had you in mind that I must be able to solve everything just by reading how to solve these? This was not mentioned to me. I find your argument very weird.

Comment: @user160137  If you are a student doing this for homework, then you already learned that $-(a+b)=-a-b$. There is no way a teacher would give you the problem you posted without first teaching you the basics.. If you are self learning and you did not learn that yet, then go back one chapter in the book you are using and start there.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. That last comment cleared it up. I did knew -(a+b)= -a-b. But not that the equation can be written that way.

Answer (score 2):

Easier: just notice the first two fractions can be written as
$$
\frac{3x}{x+2} +\frac{4x}{x-2} = \frac{7x^2 +2x}{x^2-4}
$$
Now you have a common denominator with the third fraction and it should be a piece of cake/

Comment: Yes, thank you. 5xum explained how I can turn it in a plus sign. I get it now.